# Swift framework binary

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

Previously I compiled a framework using objective-C and the framework still works after 2 years but for Swift I keep on getting `Module compiled with previous Swift version and cannot be imported to the new Swift version`.

Is there a way or configuration that I need to set to make sure that the swift framework I compiled can still be used for years to come?

Comment: No - Do a search for "Swift ABI stability" for more details and wait for Swift 5.  You "could" use Carthage's "binary only" support, but you'd still need to provide binaries for each version of Swift/Xcode you want to support - and welcome to my hell for the last 3 or so years :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift does not have binary compatibility with old versions. :((
You can read about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2).
Apple said what Swift 5  will have [ABI stability](https://swift.org/abi-stability/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I'll wait for Swift 5 then.

Comment: Don't forget, that Swift 5.x will not have ABI compatibility with versions less than 5.0 (with 4.2, 4.0 and so on).